# Why aren't my member variables filled when I use discord.utils.get()?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The ID-s are the correct 18 number ones from discord, the intents and bot rights are set properly, yet both fetches come back with None.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    user1 = discord.utils.get(after.guild.members, name="botid")
    user2 = discord.utils.get(after.guild.members, name="myid")

    if after.id == user1.id and before.roles != after.roles and user2 in after.roles:
        roles_added = [role for role in after.roles if role not in before.roles]
        roles_removed = [role for role in before.roles if role not in after.roles]

        if roles_added:
            await after.remove_roles(*roles_added, reason="Automated action: roles cannot be assigned to user1 by user2")
        elif roles_removed:
            await after.add_roles(*roles_removed, reason="Automated action: roles cannot be removed from user1 by user2")
```

A basic role bot that prevents a specific user(me) to set roles to another user(the bot)

Comment: Don't you want `id="...botid..."` and not `name=`?

Comment: According to the docs the 18 digit discord ID should be used, but changing the name to id, or changing the ID to the actual username or nickname in the server still doesn't yield results. All return none.